# The role of policy optimization in model-based RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

So I have a simulation $M_{sim}$ that approximates a nonlinear dynamic robotic model $M_{real}$ by solving a set of nonlinear differential equations. Given $M_{sim}$, I use an agent $A$ (namely, I use $PPO$, which is a policy optimization method), to find an optimal policy $\pi^*$ w.r.t to some reward term $R$.

Though I did receive some good results (was able to increase the *return* over time), It crossed my mind that I'm actually mixing approaches from different worlds - if $M_{sim}$ is given, then we are dealing with *model-based RL*, and if so, how is that reasonable to use policy optimization, that by definition does not assume anything about the world?

At least in terms of taxonomy, it would have been more reasonable if the learning process of $A$ would occur on $M_{real}$, as this is considered *model-free*, but when $M_{sim}$ is used, all the notion of using policy optimization only with model-free approaches doesn't seem to work.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A model-free RL algorithm means that the algorithm does not know how the environment works. In your case, your agent receives states and rewards from your simulation model and uses this data to update the policy by trial-and-error. Therefore, it is still model-free (but in a simulated environmnet). This is not different than standard RL benchmark environments, like the torque simulators such as MuJoCo.

A model-based RL algorithm would know how the environment works (or at least learn it) and would be able to plan actions by using the knowledge of the environment. If you want that the agent uses the differential equations of the simulator to get a better performance, you can try other approaches such as model predictive control.